# Does this limit always exist?

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Here is the question; it may seem very simple, but it is difficult (at least for me).

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $R$ that is strictly increasing, and suppose $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is a periodic function with period 1.

Prove that for all $x\in R$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f^n(x)}{n}$ exists.

In an equivalent formulation, the dynamic system $(X,T)$ is quasi-regular, where $X=[0,1],T: x\mapsto x+\{g(x)\}$. I.e. the Birkhoff average $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n\leq N}T^n(x)$ exists for all $x\in X$.

Comment: What makes you think the statement is true?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, a friend ask me weather it is true... It seems I can construct counter-example in the continuous case but there still be some obstacle. This is come from Poincare's original definition of wind number. And which seems is not the satisfied one due to it is different with the definition on the book dynamic system of Pollinate.

Comment: And it seem to be true for $f$ is $C^1$ at least or may be we only need $f$ is lipchitz? I am not very sure.

Comment: see Poincare's original definition of rotation number in   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number.

Comment: I introduce why my intuition is this result could be right at least for $f$ with good regularity.  It is just come from the observation that if the flow of points induce by interaction is uniformly distribute under some invariant measure on $X$, then the time average need to coincide with the space average which lead to the result of the existence of limit, and given a representation of it.

Comment: But when the regularity is not very good, unfortunately there is some obstacle for the connectedness of the flow on the whole space, there is a lots of crack that the flow could permeate in and never go out which lead to the result at least there do not exist a absolutely continuous measure $\mu$ make the time average coincide with the space average associated to $\mu$ .

Comment: A example of the permeate could be a very small open set $A$ with a zero point of $f$ as right endpoint and $f$ is strictly decreasing on $A$, and combine with the result $f'>-1$ deduce form the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDITED: below I give a counter example in the case where $f$ is not monotonic. The question you’re asking is well known to be true in the monotonic case**

There's a counterexample (even if $f$ is highly regular). I'll give a piecewise linear counterexample: let 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}4x&\text{if $x\in [0,\frac 12)$;}\\
3-2x&\text{if $x\in [\frac 12,1)$};
\end{cases}
$$
and extend to the real line by periodicity.

Let $g(x)$ be the corresponding map from the circle to itself. 
Now let $J_0=[0,\frac 14)$ and $J_1=[\frac 14,\frac 12)$. Both of these intervals map bijectively to the whole circle. Now you can define 
$J_{i_0\ldots i_{n-1}}=J_{i_0}\cap g^{-1}J_{i_1}\cap \ldots\cap g^{-(n-1)}J_{i_{n-1}}$. 
Finally for any sequence of 0's and 1's, you can define $h(z)=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty J_{z_0\ldots z_n}$. For $x\in\mathbb R$, let $\rho^+(x)=\limsup f^n(x)/n$ and $\rho^-(x)=\liminf f^n(x)/n$. It's not hard to check that $\rho^+(h(z))=\limsup (z_0+\ldots+z_{n-1})/n$ and $\rho^-(h(z))=\liminf (z_0+\ldots+z_{n-1})/n$. In particular, it's easy to construct points with $\rho^-(x)=a$ and $\rho^+(x)=b$ for any $0\le a\le b\le 1$.

Comment: It seems in your construction if and only if $0=i_0=i_1=...=i_{n-1}=...$ could make $\cap_{n=0}^{\infty}J_{z_0z_1...z_{n}}\neq \emptyset$. But in this case there is no contradiction.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstand your construction.

Comment: $J_{0100}$ consists of points in $J_0$ that map into $J_1$ at the first time step; and $J_0$ at the second and third time steps. These are always non-empty since the intervals $J_i$ are mapped over the entire circle, so that $g^4(J_{0010})$ maps over the whole circle. This means you can find a sub-interval of $J_{0010}$ mapped over either $J_i$ by $g^4$. The intersection is of a nested sequence of intervals. You have to be slightly careful with the right endpoint (or modify the example to allow you to use closed intervals).

Comment: I totally understand your construction, this is a very clever construction. Thanks a lot! So the expender map is extremely complex, and there is a lot things with possibility to happen in it.

Comment: Em... due to $f$ is said to be strictly increasing in my assume, this very good example you provide seems not to be a counterexample  because for the $f$ in your construction, $f'=-2\leq -1$ for $x\in [\frac{1}{2},1)$ so this example is out of the range we consider...

Comment: The trajectory of $0$ under iteration of $f$, is just $0$. The trajectory of $1/40$ is $\{1,4,16,64,112,136,184...\}/40$. The picture becomes clearer if we take first differences: $\{3,12,48,48,24,48,48,24..\}/40$ which is periodic and with long term mean $1$. Nice counterexample!

Comment: Ahh. @Huxiyu is right! I also got confused between $f$ and $g$ having to have derivative $\ge -1$.

Comment: Sorry. If you want a result for strictly increasing functions, the answer is well known. See Devaney’s book on chaotic dynamical systems for example. As you say, this is just the (Poincaré) rotation number which exists for all $x$ (and is independent of $x$).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas,@Yaakov Baruch, appreciate for your help, now I have a fully understanding of the problem. ;)